# Ajax Post Request Not hitting web method asp.net web forms(.Net 4.5)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

**Ajax request**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            alert("clicked");
            var postdata = new Object();
            postdata.FirstName = $('#txtFirstName').val();
            postdata.Mobile = $('#txtMobile').val();
            postdata.Email = $("#CPH_Sections_txtEmail").val();
            postdata.Password = $("#CPH_Sections_txtPassword").val();
            postdata.Code = $('#txtCode').val();

            var postdata = { harisModel: postdata };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '~/Register.aspx/testfy',
                data: JSON.stringify(postdata) ,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                                        alert("success" + data.d);
         },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Status: " + jqXHR.status + "; Error: " + jqXHR.responseText);              
         }

     });

        });
    });
```

**Webmethod**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string testfy(HarisModel harisModel)
{    
   return "{'returnstatus':'true'}"; 
}
```

**Model Class**

```
public class HarisModel
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string Mobile { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }


    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

}
```

**issue Description:**
Ajax call not hitting web method

Comment: '~/Register.aspx/testfy' can be the problem. Ok, ~ means the root of the virtual application when used in a server context, but when you use it on the client side like this, the request will hit the server as is. Can you just try replacing the ~ with the name of your virtual app like /MyApp/Register.aspx/testfy?

Comment: Change your `url` to: `Register.aspx/testfy`

Comment: Thank You So Much Brother issue resolved by removing "~"  sign